# ASP.NET Core Razor - redirecting from a dependency injected service

Tags: .net-core, razor, dependency-injection

I'm building a Razor pages website. Users are required to login to access the website.

I have a controller behind the login, e.g:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ParentParamsService _parentParams;

    public IndexModel(ParentParamsService parentParams)
    {
        _parentParams = parentParams;
    }
}
```

The idea behind `parentParamsService` is it fetches a bunch of user related data that's cached in our database.

It looks like this:

```
public class ParentParamsService
{
    private readonly ProductionDbContext _productionContext;
    private readonly ParentParamsCache _parentParamsCache;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly UserQueries _userQueries;

    private ParentParamDTO _parentParamDTO { get; set; }

    public ParentParamsService(ProductionDbContext productionContext,
                               ParentParamsCache parentParamsCache,
                               IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                               UserQueries userQueries)
    {
        _productionContext = productionContext;
        _parentParamsCache = parentParamsCache;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _userQueries = userQueries;

        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity != null && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var parentsAppTokenId = Guid.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            _init(parentsAppTokenId);
        }
    }

    private void _init(Guid parentsAppTokenId)
    {
        // get parentsAppToken
         
        var token = (from p in _productionContext.scParentsAppTokens.AsNoTracking()
                     where
                     p.ParentToken == parentsAppTokenId
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();

        if (token == null)
        {
            // If token is null for whatever reason I want to logout user / redirect to login page
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using `_httpContextAccessor` to `response.redirect` to the login page but nothing happens, when debugging the line is just skipped over.

I'm guessing I'm trying to do this the wrong way. I have many controllers where `parentParamsService` is injected into so I'd like to handle this in one place rather than checking something for null in each controller constructor.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the `HttpContextAccessor` is or isn't meant to be used that way.

But what you might be able to do is implement an `ExceptionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>> _exceptionHandlers;
    
    public ApiExceptionFilterAttribute()
    {
        _exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>>
        {
            { typeof(RedirectException), HandleRedirectException }
        };
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        HandleException(context);
        base.OnException(context);
    }
    
    private void HandleException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Type type = context.Exception.GetType();
        if (_exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            _exceptionHandlers[type].Invoke(context);
            return;
        }
    }   
    
    private void HandleRedirectException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/your-logout-url");
    }
}
```

Which handles a custom exception:

```
public class RedirectException : Exception
{

}
```

You need to register the `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute` in the startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ServiceFilterAttribute(typeof(ApiExceptionFilterAttribute)));
    })
}
```

And then you can throw the error from your `_init` method:

```
private void _init(Guid parentsAppTokenId)
{
    // get parentsAppToken
     
    var token = (from p in _productionContext.scParentsAppTokens.AsNoTracking()
                 where
                 p.ParentToken == parentsAppTokenId
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();

    if (token == null)
    {
        throw new RedirectException();
    }
}
```